# QGIS 3 Display negative values bar diagrams

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Suppose I have a dataset with an id (for each geographic entities) and 2 numeric fields NUM1 and NUM2. These numeric fields have positive and negative values.

[image]

When I use bar diagrams, only theses cases are displayed :

- NUM1 is positive, NUM2 is positive
- NUM1 is positive, NUM2 is negative
- NUM1 is negative, NUM2 is positive

[image]

If NUM1 and NUM2 are negative, the bar diagrams are missing. Same story if we only use one numeric field. Is it a bug? How to display negative values in bar diagrams?

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/12574, https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/24166

Comment: Thank you! Let's wait and see :)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/37924
It's been solved in a recent release.